# Hide Woocommerce "out of stock" products for main page using CSS

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

i trying to use CSS to hide the "out of stock" item to show at my main page only, but not work.

Can i know how to find the actual code to hide the out of stock item?

The code below i try before, but not work

```
.outofstock {display:none;}

.product_item_out_of_stock {display:none;}

.out_of_stock {display:none;}
```

Please advice.

Thank You,

ZhiJie

Comment: check in firebug there must be a extra class on out of stock products.

Comment: Please provide a link updating your question…

Answer (score 0):

add in header.

```
<style type="text/css">
.out-of-stock{display: none;}
</style>
```